# gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ... NOT_FOUND: Unknown service account

Tags: gcloud, google-iam

I am creating a new service account and trying to assign it a role. The assigning part is failing to find the account I just created.

Why?

```
*[master][~]$ gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding some-project --member="serviceAccount:some-name@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.add-iam-policy-binding) NOT_FOUND: Unknown service account

*[master][~]$ gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding some-project --member="some-name@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.add-iam-policy-binding) NOT_FOUND: Unknown service account

*[master][~]$ gcloud iam service-accounts list                                                                                                                                                           
DISPLAY NAME                            EMAIL                                                     DISABLED
Compute Engine default service account  01234567890-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com         False
App Engine default service account      some-project@appspot.gserviceaccount.com                  False
Some Name                               some-name@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com            False
```

Interestingly, the new account does not appear in **IAM & Admin > Service Accounts** in the portal, either. It still shows when I list them all from the CLI. Prrrfff...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want `gcloud projects` not `gcloud iam service-accounts`

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding some-project \
--member=serviceAccount:some-name@some-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor
```

I have a snippet that is (from memory):

```sh
PROJECT="some-project"
ACCOUNT="some-name"

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

ROLES=(
  "secretmanager.secretAccessor"
)

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Use sparingly
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--project=${PROJECT}

for ROLE in ${ROLES[@]}
do
  gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
  --member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
  --role=roles/${ROLE}
done
```

Comment: Oh yeah! That's really easy to misread in the docs!

Comment: Thanks. And now I've given it a role, it shows up in the console.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope you're enjoying the GCP onboarding.

Comment: To list and create roles https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles?project=yourprojectid.

Answer (score 0):

[Step 5](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#iam-cross-project-sa-gcloud) should do:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
    user-sa-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --member=serviceAccount:service-agent-email \
    --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```